# php многомерный массив в таблицу

Tags: php, массивы, таблицы

уважаемые знатоки,
**есть такой массив, получаемый через api**

```
Array ( 
[trading_pair] => btceur 
[orders] => Array ( 
[asks] => Array (
[0] => Array ( 
[price] => 55008 
[amount_currency_to_trade] => 0.05 )
[1] => Array ( 
[price] => 59940.1 
[amount_currency_to_trade] => 0.001  )
```

**Хочу выдать его в таблицу. Такой код я смастерила:**

```
echo '<table>';
foreach ($showOrderbookCompact['orders'] as $array1 => $asksbids )      
{ foreach ($asksbids as $array2 => $numbers ) 
{ foreach ($numbers as $priceamount )
{ echo "<table border='1'>";             
    echo "<tr>";           
    echo "<td>$array1</td>";        
    echo "<td>$array2</td>";          
    echo "<td>$priceamount</td>";       
    echo "</tr>\n";    
    echo "</table>";
}
}
}
```

**Все бы ничего, но он выдает каждую позицию по две строчки, вот так:**

asks 0 | 00000.06
asks 0 | 0.05

asks 1 | 00000.06
asks 1 | 0.001

**Мне бы хотелось, чтобы было так:**

asks 0 | 00000.06 | 0.05

asks 1 | 00000.06 | 0.001

Никак не могу добиться.
Не судите строго, я не программист, так для себя вожусь.
Спасибо заранее за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ключевая ошибка в вашем коде, в том, что не обращаетесь напрямую к массиву 'asks', а делаете вложенные foreach операторы. Из-за этого и выводится не то, что вы хотели. Пример правильного кода:

```
$array = [
    'trading_pair' => 'btceur',
    'orders' => [
        'asks' => [
            0 => [
                'price' => 55008,
                'amount_currency_to_trade' => 0.05
            ],
            1 => [
                'price' => 59940.1,
                'amount_currency_to_trade' => 0.001
            ],
        ],
    ],
]; 

echo '<table>';
foreach ($array['orders']['asks'] as $index => $data ) { 
    echo "<table border='1'>";             
    echo "<tr>";           
        echo '<td> asks - ' . $index . '</td>';        
        echo '<td>' .  $data['price'] . '</td>';          
        echo '<td>' . $data['amount_currency_to_trade'] . '</td>';       
    echo "</tr>\n";    
}   
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. То, что надо.